# Why $\operatorname{E}\left[\varepsilon \mid X\right]=0 \implies \operatorname{E}\left[X'\varepsilon\right]=0$ in a Multiple Linear Regression Model.

Tags: statistics

Consider a model in matrix form such as, $$Y=X\beta+\varepsilon$$

that respects all Gauss-Markov assumptions.

It's known that, $$\operatorname{E}\left[\varepsilon \mid X\right]=0 \implies \operatorname{E}\left[\varepsilon\right]=0 \text{ and } \operatorname{Cov}\left(X,\varepsilon\right)=0$$

But in matrix notation I saw that $$\operatorname{Cov}\left(X, \varepsilon\right)=\operatorname{E}\left[X' \varepsilon\right]=0$$

I know how to prove that $\operatorname{E}\left[X' \varepsilon\right]=0$: $$\operatorname{E}\left[X' \varepsilon\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[\operatorname{E}\left[X' \varepsilon \mid X\right]\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[X'\operatorname{E}\left[ \varepsilon \mid X\right]\right]=\operatorname{E}\left[X'0\right]=0$$

But I dont' know how to prove why $\operatorname{Cov}\left(X, \varepsilon\right)=\operatorname{E}\left[X' \varepsilon\right]$

If someone could help me with this second part, it would be great.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$Cov(X,\epsilon)=E(X'\epsilon)-E(\epsilon)E(.)=E(X'\epsilon )$$

Comment: So, I saw a formula similar two that $$Cov(X,Y)=E(XY')-E(X)E'(Y)$$ which is a little bit different in the order of multiplication from yours.

Comment: So this is not a var/cov matrix, is it just a way of calculating the covariance between each regressor and the error term?

Comment: @CedroPrispim Yes.